# PHP MySQL Query to check if record exists or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following data in the table..

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| activity_id | activity_name | main_unit_id |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|           1 | DEA           |           67 |
|           2 | DEB           |           68 |
|           3 | DEC           |           68 |
|           4 | fasdfsadf     |           74 |
+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

i want to add another activity, but before adding i have to make sure that same activity name is not there against an main_unit_id...
I write following query,

```
$SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_query(
    "SELECT count(*) FROM activities " .
    "WHERE main_unit_id = '67' and activity_name = 'DEA'"
);
$RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_num_rows($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY);
echo $RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY;
```

then it print 1 which means a activity against this project already exists...

```
$SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_query(
    "SELECT count(*) FROM activities " .
    "WHERE main_unit_id = '78' and activity_name = 'afsdaf'"
);
$RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_num_rows($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY);
echo $RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY;
```

then it print 1 which means a activity against this project already exists...
but there is no record in this case....

Comment: The reason you are getting 1 in the second case is that you are looking at the number of rows returned and not the value itself. The query returns one row with the value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE main_unit_id = '".$project."' and activity_name = '67' limit 1");
    if(mysql_fetch_row($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY)) {
        echo 'a activity against this project already exists...';
      }
      else{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add another activity, but do not want duplicates on `main_unit_id`, then the right approach is to create a unique index (or constraint) on the field:

```
create unique index idx_activities_mainunitid on activites(main_unit_id);
```

If you attempt to insert a duplicate, the insert will fail.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_num_rows` will return the number of rows, not the `count(*)` result.

In the first test, `count(*)` will return 1 in **one** row, so the result will be 1.

In the second test, `count(*)` will return 0 in **one** row, so the result would still be 1.

You will need to use a fetch function to get the result of `count(*)` rather than `mysql_num_rows`.

**Edit**

I.e. from:

```
$RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY = mysql_num_rows($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY);
```

To:

```
list ($RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY) = mysql_fetch_row($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY);
```

> <sup>**Note**: The use of the `mysql_*` functions are considered *deprecated* and  you should instead use something that offers better security and more functionality, such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).</sup>

Comment: i know that, but how will i get status in my case.

Comment: Replace the lines with `mysql_num_rows` with `list ($RESULT_SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY) = mysql_fetch_row($SQL_CHECK_ACTIVITY);`. See edit.